# JSON from js to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

today I'm trying to get JSON from my JS part of code and pass it to c# method.
The problem that I got null when I have passed the result to the current method.

Here is my JS part:

```
    GMaps.on('click',
                    map.map,
                    function(event) {

                        markers.push(new Point(map.markers.length, event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()));


                        var index = map.markers.length;
                        var lat = event.latLng.lat();
                        var lng = event.latLng.lng();
                        map.addMarker({
                            lat: lat,
                            lng: lng,
                            title: 'Marker #' + index
                        });
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(markers));
                    });

                function TestJSON() {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("ReturnJson","Home")",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(markers),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json"
                });
                };
```

As you see from the code, in console I see that array of markers is not empty and after every new click I add a value to the array.
When I will locate all markers I want to save it, so I made a button for it.

Here is my data model:

```
public class TripPoint

{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

}

public class TripRoute
{
    public List<TripPoint> route = new List<TripPoint>();
}
```

It how looks like my html code:

```
  <form>
            <button type="button" value="Save your route " onclick="TestJSON()"></button>
        </form>
```

And at last it how looks like the method which should get JSON string

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReturnJson(string json)
    {
        //  **********************************
        //  PROBLEM HERE: json is null
        //  **********************************

        TripRoute route = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TripRoute>(json);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Please, help to find out why I get a null string.

**upd.**

Here is my route config

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "ReturnJSON",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ReturnJSON", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
    }
}
```

Comment: What variable is null? When? Are you saying `route` in `ReturnJson()` is null or empty? Or some string somewhere? What does `JSON.stringify(markers)` return?

Comment: Please show what you have in the RouteCollection. I mean in RegisterRoutes method in the Global.asax.cs.

Comment: @EdPlunkett oh, in the method ReturnJson a parameter "string" json is null. When I press a button (as I understand this) should me called the function TestJson in JS which passes the json value to c sharp method. Am I wrong?

What does JSON.stringify(markers) return?
As I think it returns data in json format.

Comment: @Antipod oh, ok, I added it to the question. Please, take a look on it.

Comment: `ReturnJson` is a member of your Home controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items you are adding to the markers is with properties `lat`,`long` and `title`, but your view model (Which you are trying to serialize to) has different property names. So i suggest you to create a class with same property names

```
public class MarkerItem
{
  public string Title {set;get;}
  public decimal Lat {set;get;}
  public string Long { set;get;}
}
```

and since you want to send an an array of marker's, use a collection of the above class as your parameter. You do not need to use a string as parameter and deserialize it again. **The Default model binder will be able to map the posted data to a list of `MarkerItem` class object**s

```
public ActionResult ReturnJson(List<MarkerItem> markerItems)
{
    //do something with markerItems list
    // to do : Return something
}
```

I just noticed your routeconfig. You do not need the second route registration. Your default route registration is good enough.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
}
```

Comment: This the way to do it. But what if she wants to have a string and then deserialize it.

Comment: @Antipod  Actually, I want to ask which way is better: to have a string and then serialize it or get it at once to list (is it self-serialized inside)?

Comment: There is no reason to use a string and deserialize. **The default model binder is created to map your posted data to your method parameters(assuming the names match)**. reading as string and serializing seems duplicate and unnecessary as model binder does that for you.

Comment: Of course it is the right way to use the strongly-typed class, no doubt. Or you have to have a strong reason why you cannot use it.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now it's pretty clear. Thanks to both of you, guys.